# Gimp crashes in 15.04

Tags: gimp

From a command line start, gimp tries to start and load stuff, but then this:

```
This is a development version of GIMP.  Debug messages may appear here.
(gimp:6339): Gimp-Widgets-CRITICAL **: gimp_device_info_set_device: assertion '(info->device == NULL && GDK_IS_DEVICE (device)) || (GDK_IS_DEVICE (info->device) && device == NULL)' failed
 mapped '<Toolbox>/Xtns/Batch/Batch Process...' to '<Image>/Filters/Extensions/Batch/Batch Process...'
 mapped '<Toolbox>/Xtns/Misc' to '<Image>/File/Create/Misc'
 mapped '<Toolbox>/Xtns/Photo' to '<Image>/Filters/Extensions/Photo'
gimp: ../../../../src/cairo-scaled-font.c:459: _cairo_scaled_glyph_page_destroy: Assertion `!scaled_font->cache_frozen' failed.
gimp: terminated: Aborted
(script-fu:6367): LibGimpBase-WARNING **: script-fu: gimp_wire_read(): error
```

This is after a purge or two. Installed from Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: You use that gimp-edge repository (by otto-kesselgulasch), right?

Comment: No, just the Ubuntu regular version from Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: The Ubuntu Software Center offers whatever is in the configured repositories. Please check which ones you have set.

Comment: I don't understand. I have no special gimp repo, (no kesselgulasch). Isn't the problem to be read in the error message? Does someone understand what the error is trying to say?

Comment: @user78162 we understand what it is saying -read the first line. That's why he's asking these questions.

Answer (score 1):

The error message starts with:

```
This is a development version of GIMP.
```

This means that you do **not** run a stable version of GIMP. Stable in the same meaning as an Ubuntu release - updates for bugs and security issues do happen, but you do not get new features.

You've got a development version of GIMP installed - probably the one from https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp-edge

You probably ran the following command at some time ago:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge
```

Many people think that this is not persistent, i.e. it will only be used for the next upgrade and install, and revert back later on. This assumption is wrong, unfortunately.

In order to remove repositories you have added this way, use:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge
```

---

**Addendum**

It could be that you want to run a development version of GIMP, of course - but your comments so far do not give me confidence that this is the case.

It could also have been a different repository, of course - same principle, though, and the one I mentioned is the most popular by far.

And last but not least, I tried to convince the maintainer of that repository to make it possible to have both the standard stable GIMP from Ubuntu's default repositories and the development version from his repository installed - but he refuses to do that.

Comment: Did everything you said and installed from USC, but it still crashes: (gimp:29296): Gimp-Widgets-CRITICAL **: gimp_device_info_set_device: assertion '(info->device == NULL && GDK_IS_DEVICE (device)) || (GDK_IS_DEVICE (info->device) && device == NULL)' failed
gimp: ../../../../src/cairo-scaled-font.c:459: _cairo_scaled_glyph_page_destroy: Assertion `!scaled_font->cache_frozen' failed.
gimp: terminated: Aborted

(script-fu:29303): LibGimpBase-WARNING **: script-fu: gimp_wire_read(): error

Comment: Just solved it! Apparently, I can't use the Numix theme. Odd, but switching to the defalut Adwaita theme solved the problem. An explanation would be nice, if anyone knows why. . .